# why can't my spring-cloud-stream mockito test Autowire my Processor?

Tags: mockito, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to create tests for my spring-cloud-stream project. I've created my own BizSyncProcessor interface instead of using the default Processor, which seems to be in all the documentation. I've done this kind of project before with tests, but can't remember if I used mockito at the same time, so I'm wondering if that's the issue, because I'm doing @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) instead of @RunWith(SpringRunner).

I also had [similar problems when building the actual app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53818113/why-cant-spring-autowire-my-cloud-stream-processor), before I included the rabbit implementation as a dependency in maven.

IntelliJ flags an error on the @Autowired BizSyncProcessor saying 'no Beans of type 'BizSyncProcessor' could be found. However I'm able to run the test, so it compiles, but then bizSyncProcessor is null when running the test.

I'm including mockito because the handler that listens for the message makes a call to another service (the SFISClient), so I'm mocking out that call.

Here's my test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@EnableBinding(BizSyncProcessor.class)
public class UpdatedBusinessHandlerTest {

    @Autowired
    private BizSyncProcessor bizSyncProcessor;

    @Autowired
    private MessageCollector messageCollector;

    @Mock
    SFISClient sfisClient;

    @InjectMocks
    UpdatedBusinessHandler updatedBusinessHandler;

    @Test
    public void testWiring() throws Exception {
        UpdatedBusinessAlert updatedBusinessAlert = new UpdatedBusinessAlert();
        updatedBusinessAlert.setBusinessId(UUID.randomUUID());
        Message<UpdatedBusinessAlert> updatedBusinessAlertMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(updatedBusinessAlert).build();
        bizSyncProcessor.writeUpdatedBusinessIds().send(updatedBusinessAlertMessage);

        Message<BusinessFlooringSummary> businessFlooringSummaryMessage = (Message<BusinessFlooringSummary>) messageCollector.forChannel(bizSyncProcessor.writeFlooringSummaries()).poll();
        BusinessFlooringSummary businessFlooringSummary = businessFlooringSummaryMessage.getPayload();
        assertNotNull(businessFlooringSummary);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@SpringBootTest` and everything Spring-based are not going to work in your case because you don't use `@RunWith(SpringRunner)`. There is just nothing what can trigget those Spring hooks.

On the other hand there is no reason to use a `MockitoJUnitRunner`. You simply can rely on the `@MockBean` instead for your `SFISClient`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans

Comment: Thanks; I had mistakenly assumed that MockitoJUnitRunner extended SpringRunner, or somehow brought in the base Spring context; I was wrong